# PHP::FTP Change file permission

Tags: php

Im doing php pipe email functionality i am able to upload file from email and i am uploading file(jpg,png..) in my folder.

problem  is when access  that file from FTP or Browser that file not opening. and uploaded files permissions code default showing  600 and "-rw----" and owner/group showing 99 99.

i need to change permissions to 644 and 502 100. 
in my script i used:

```
chmod("/var/www/html/quantumcrew/blogpdf/",0777);
```

how can i change owner permissions from my script(mail pipe script).

Comment: What is mail pipe script? "change permissions to 644 and 502 100" - What does this mean?

Comment: in our ftp files if we change file permissions to 644 or 777 then every one can access that file...and 502 100 is also like that...

Comment: Okay. Do you need to change ownership, or change permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change ownership you would need to use **chown**. http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

```
chown("/var/www/html/quantumcrew/blogpdf/", 502);
```